# windbg break on file open

Tags: debugging, windbg

I have a .net application which I don't have source too.  I'm interested in determining what files this application is accessing.  I thought that a debugger would be a good way to do this.  I work only in the linux world and know nothing about windows debuggers.  I feel like there should be a way to do this with windbg, I know how I would go about it with gdb but not with windbg.  Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to monitor file system activity for a given process then you won't find anything better than [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). It does lots more too and it's free from Sysinternals (now Microsoft).

> Process Monitor is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity. It combines
>   the features of two legacy
>   Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and
>   Regmon, and adds an extensive list of
>   enhancements including rich and
>   non-destructive filtering,
>   comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable
>   process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support
>   for each operation, simultaneous
>   logging to a file, and much more. Its
>   uniquely powerful features will make
>   Process Monitor a core utility in your
>   system troubleshooting and malware
>   hunting toolkit.

Comment: This gives me just what I need.  Thank you for telling me about this great application.

Answer (score 0):

Stu is right if you just want to know what files are being accessed. 
But if you want to know more about debugging .net apps, you can place break points on .net code when you have SOS.dll loaded into windbg. It's more involved than I can describe here, but you can Google windbg and SOS.DLL to find more info. Tess Ferrandez has a great blog that you may find useful, too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/